# MySQL filtering result from a foreign key that doesn't have contents

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_category` (
  `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `score_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sub_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  KEY `sub_code` (`sub_code`)
) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `correct_ans` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `incorrect1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `incorrect2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `incorrect3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `test_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image_location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  KEY `test_cat` (`test_cat`)
)

ALTER TABLE `questions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `questions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`test_cat`) REFERENCES `test_category` (`_id`);
```

so basically these two tables are related. questions table is related to test_category table through the foreign key test_cat from the table questions referenced to the _id of test_category. what i wan't to display is those entry from test_category that have a entries related to it from the questions table. if  an entry from test_category doesn't have anything referenced to it from the questions table then it shouldn't be displayed.

```
select distinct test_category._id, test_category.score_type 
from test_category join questions 
where ??
```

that's the sql i have tried but i don't know how to filter it with where...

Comment: Ah sorry the above will display if its not in the question table just change it and make it inner JOIN , my bad, `JOIN join questions on questions.test_cat = test_category._id`

Comment: test_category.id is not null field. Will you be inserting null values into questions.test_cat?

Comment: @Nisha questions.test_cat is a required field

Comment: Ha, now i get it. You will be having records in table1 without corresponding records in table2. These are the records that you need.!! Use a join appropriately.

Comment: yeah, im on to that.. it's kinda confusing and tricky though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct test_category._id, test_category.score_type from test_category 
join questions
on 'questions.test_cat' = 'test_category._id'
```

Comment: it still display an entry from test_category that isn't referenced from the table questions

Comment: In oracle we use left joins, left outer join. Just check out for similar features in mysql.

Comment: @ChristianBurgos: May be you can upvote and accept as answer since it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct test_category._id, test_category.score_type from test_category 
join questions
on questions.test_cat = test_category._id
```

kudos to Nisha and  Abhik Chakraborty